# for any polynomial $f(t)$,we have that $f(A)$ is the matrix representation of $f(T)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be the matrix representation of a linear transformation $T$ from $V$ to $V$. Prove that, for any polynomial $f(t)$,we have that $f(A)$ is the matrix representation of $f(T)$.

How can I start proving such a statement? Can I prove it without using induction.

Thanks.

Comment: *Hint*: If $T_1 : V \to W$ and $T_2 : W \to Z$ are two linear maps, $A$ is the matrix representation of $T_1$, and $B$ is the matrix representation of $T_2$, then $BA$ is the matrix representation of $T_2T_1$. Also, the map that assigns to each linear map its matrix representation, is linear.

Comment: @azif00 Thanks  ...

Comment: you have to show the linearity of $f(T)$ and then use the base vectors.

Comment: You'll have an easier time doing this if you introduce explicit notation for taking matrix representations with respect to a basis $B$. A pretty standard choice is $[T]_B$. Now show that $[-]_B$ is a *ring homomorphism

Answer (score 3):

The short answer to your question seems to be:

Let $v \in V$.  Show that $f(A)(v) = f(T)(v)$.  Conclude that $f(A)$ and $f(T)$ are the same function.  Observe that $f(A)$ is a matrix, so $f(A)$ is the/a matrix representation of $f(T)$.  (Whether "the" or "a" depends on other facts you may or may not have.  If you don't have uniqueness of representation by some other means, you need to show uniqueness as well.)

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ is the matrix representation of $T$ then there is some basis $v_k$ such that
$\sum_k [Ae_i]_k v_k = T v_i$.

If we apply $T$ to both sides we see that
\begin{eqnarray}
T(\sum_k [Ae_i]_k v_k) &=& \sum_k [Ae_i]_k Tv_k \\
&=&  \sum_k [Ae_i]_k \sum_j [Ae_k]_j v_j \\
&=& \sum_k \sum_j [Ae_i]_k [Ae_k]_j v_j \\
&=& \sum_k [A^2e_i]_k v_k \\
&=& T^2 v_i
\end{eqnarray}
It is not hard to see that if we repeat this process we get
$\sum_k [A^ne_i]_k v_k = T^n v_i$, and from there that
$f(T)v_i = \sum_{n=0}^N a_n T^nv_i =  \sum_{n=0}^N a_n  \sum_k [A^n e_i]_k v_k = \sum_k [\sum_{n=0}^N a_n A^n e_i]_k v_k = \sum_k [f(A) e_i]_k v_k$